# Why can't I post a question on stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

What happened to automatically gaining 100 rep for sites in order to post questions if sufficient rep on a sister stack?

I cannot post a question on `stackexchange.com`.

There is no "ask" button:

[image: No post button]

Comment: There is no "Stack Exchange" site proper to post questions on. Meta.SE exists for questions about the entire network. The central stackexchange.com is merely a hub for sites.

Comment: Also, the 100 rep bonus isn't to let you post questions. You can post questions on every stack with 1 rep (which is the minimum rep possible to have). The bonus gives you other stuff, like making/editing CW, upvoting, commenting, flagging, posting links and images, etc.

Comment: Not sure how "...........wat? You have assoc." is a beneficial comment deserving of upvotes.  Someone is clearly boosting.

Comment: **Please stop changing your question**. If you have a new question to ask, then just post a new question.

Comment: Don't sweat the downvotes. Folks sometimes get too focused on "well OBVIOUSLY you can't do that" and can't find it in themselves to move past an easily answered (and not even that common) support question. You might want to do some research into the discussions around the features you tried to propose by editing your question here, though. Those have all been discussed in the past and aren't implemented for a reason.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

stackexchange.com only aggregates information from other network sites. It's a portal, if you will. There is no way for anyone to post on it directly.

Comment: Thank you.  Which stack do I need to post on for something general relating to technology ?

Comment: @SanuelJackson There's no catch-all site like that. If you need help selecting the right site, you can post here and tag your question [discussion] and [site-recommendation]. Include some details on what your question is about.

Comment: @SanuelJackson - FYI, there is this community-managed post about [choosing a (computing) technology-related stack for your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 2):

AdamLear has answered your actual question, but regarding your reasons for the feature request and dislike of downvotes (etc):

Your "original" question was fine, but it's fairly easy to *learn* without asking how the stackexchange.com site works.

I can *sincerely* understand why it might be confusing how the stackexchange.com site works, and no-one is expecting you to magically know, but read a little, do some searching.

In 10 mins of reading you'd have likely found out.

This however was not the reason for *all* of your downvotes!

### Downvotes

You stated:

> Downvoting simply because you think it's dumb or whatever crisis is
>   happening psychologically, is being ignorant (informal: discourteous
>   or rude)

*Resulting in more downvotes.*

You edited your question to a full blown feature request entirely different to your original question.
Change of question = people's comments became obsolete, their time wasted. Yannis had to rollback and comment to you.
*Resulting in more downvotes.*

Your new "feature-request" has been asked and debated over and over and over again. So it was also a dupe.
*Resulting in more downvotes.*

Downvotes for feature requests on Meta are also for "I do not like this idea, I do not want it implementing".
*Resulting in more downvotes.*

With your changing the question, people started flagging and reviewing to close for "not sure what you are asking".
This is all a waste of people's time, and the overall view of your "actions" now seems a bit negative and frantic.
*Resulting in more downvotes.*

Also, don't complain about downvotes when you rant and *actively ask for them*:

> Vote me down to 1 for all i care, just shows that ignorant (inf) is
>   more rampant

*Resulting in more downvotes.*

### You already had your "answer"

You got your answer just over an hour after asking your original question:

You asked: 18:38

Brad Larson commented: 19:50

> There is no "Stack Exchange" site proper to post questions on. Meta.SE
>   exists for questions about the entire network. The central
>   stackexchange.com is merely a hub for sites.

Adam Lear answered: 19:55

> stackexchange.com only aggregates information from other network
>   sites. It's a portal, if you will. There is no way for anyone to post
>   on it directly.

So your debating, ranting, and offending users was simply not necessary.
If you disagree with someone, voice your opinion, but do so in a *civil* manner, and you may find the response back to you is not only friendly, but also useful and inform you of something you were not aware of.

As proven with the helpful answer and comments surrounding AdamLear's answer :)

### Be nice

Not everyone is nice, and you will always get people making rude or snidey remarks to you, and even downvoting because they got out of the wrong side of bed. Nothing can be done about this, people are allowed their opinion as you are.

However, for the most part, 99% of users are decent. 
And if you use the site in the way it was intended - i.e. don't rant, read a bit first, don't change your question, etc - then you will find people are more welcoming and you would have received helpful comments back!

That said, not even decent folks will stand for their time being wasted or being offended when all they were trying to do was help you and answer.

"*if people stop being ignorant and voting down a well formed question*"
If someone stated that to you, are you going to be ok with it? Or, would you downvote and not help the person because they are rude?

---

Had you retained your original question and not gone through the changing and ranting and arguing with others, you would likely have not received many downvotes, and I would bet with a few upvotes you would have ended up with a *positive* net rep!

Comment: Actually, I had 15 downvotes prior to my response and altering my question to something different.   Appreciate the observations and the 'breakdown' as to how it appeared, although I can see the timestamps of the responses (and if you note, my thanks for polite and relative responses).  Treat those as you wish to be treated, and I, in kind will treat you the same way that I am treated. [The Golden Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule) is not difficult to follow indeed, and you will find that some people will respond in kind to such behavior, either positive, or negative.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this statement :  **99% of users are decent**.  I could not find anything to corroborate this idealism.  I do see a growing trend in those with large rep pools trying to maintain their top position by deleting their "bad" answers, and downvoting those up-and-coming -- now that stackexchange rank is worth $$$ -- esp with the newish "Jobs" feature. This by no means is anything new in respect to the way psychopaths maintain their positions in the real world.   Sly > Honest   IRL